# Prevent TextInput box from starting small

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I didn't have this problem before, but for some reason right now, my text input box is starting with 0 and it won't start with the place holder I had set. When I delete the 0 when I start entering, it goes away and sort of expands, with the place holder seen. Does anyone have any advice on how I can make it start with a full-text input banner and without the 0?

Here are pictures of what is happening:

[Starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzQRz.jpg)

[After clicking into text input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYxL7.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
 return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
             
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder='Blood Pressure'
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    multiline
                    onChangeText={(bp) => this.setState({ bp })}
                    value={`${this.state.bp}`}

                />
               

                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress=
                    {
                        this.updateInfo,
                        this.onFooterLinkPress
                    }
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Submit Data</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
```

Styles:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 5,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    title: {

    },
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 120,
        width: 90,
        alignSelf: "center",
        margin: 30
    },
    input: {
        height: 48,
        borderRadius: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginLeft: 30,
        marginRight: 30,
        paddingLeft: 16
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: '#788eec',
        marginLeft: 30,
        marginRight: 30,
        marginTop: 20,
        height: 48,
        borderRadius: 5,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonTitle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    footerView: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 20
    },
    footerText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#2e2e2d'
    },
    footerLink: {
        color: "#788eec",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 16
    }
})
```

Comment: Your problem is in the styles, can you post the styles?

Comment: Just posted styles!

Comment: Additionally, I was able to get the text input box to expand back, however not sure how to get rid of the default 0 value the input box is starting with

Comment: Actually was able to find the issue, I had set the default value as 0 in my constructor and did not realize it. Thank you!